# how to insert data into extra columns of target avro table when source table is having less no of columns compared to target using hive or impala?

Tags: impala, hive

Suppose I am having a source Avro table having 10 columns and my target Avro table is having 12 columns, while inserting data into the target table I need to add null values to the extra 2 columns.

But when I execute the below query it has thrown the exception

> AnalysisException: Target table 'target_table' has more columns (8) than the SELECT / VALUES clause returns (7)

```
insert overwrite table target_table select * from source_table;
```

How to make advantage of Avro table automatic schema change detection here?

**Note:** Suppose if I want to insert only 5 columns to the target and the rest should be default null. So how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify which columns you want to insert into in the insert statement. In the statement you wrote, the engine doesn't know which 7 columns out of the 8 to put the data in.
http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-5-x/topics/impala_insert.html

```
Insert overwrite table target_table (col1, col2, col3, ...) 
Select col1, col2, col3 ... From source_table;
```

`NULL` will be inserted into columns not mentioned in the column list.